# I cant add the JPanel I have over ride to the frame. it is not displaying

Tags: java, swing, awt

I can not add the jpanel I have over ride to the frame. it is not displaying it. I have add it by get content pane but it doesn't work.what should I do.
where is my problem.
thank you in advance

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class BigBang {
    JFrame worldFrame;
    WorldPanel worldPanel;
    int worldX=800;
    int worldY=600;
    public void draw(){
        worldFrame=new JFrame("world");
        worldFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        worldPanel=new WorldPanel(new Dimension(800,600));
        worldFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        worldFrame.setSize(worldX,worldY);
        worldFrame.getContentPane().add(worldPanel);
        System.out.println("done");
        worldFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigBang b=new BigBang();
        b.draw();
    }
}
class WorldPanel extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Graphics graphic;   
    WorldPanel(Dimension d){
        setPreferredSize(d);
    }
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        System.out.println("it is in");
        graphic=g;
        setBackground(Color.black);
        int firstx=60;
        int firsty=90;
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillOval(firstx, firsty, 30, 30); 
        System.out.println("here");
    }
}
```

Comment: Delete the `s` from `paintComponents`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have spelling mistake you need to override `paintComponent()` method, but you have overrided `paintComponents()`. Change method in `WorldPanel` class, that helps.

Comment: Good catch - funny how programming errors often boil down to one character :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you had used `@Override` annotation, your compiler would have produced an error because this method does not override anything :) Using this annotation is a good habit IMO.

```
@Override
public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Override method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
...
}
```

instead of paintComponents in WorldPanel

Comment: -1 for the `it works for me` comment. When you get a large number of downvotes you should ask why if you don't understand the reason.  Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method, not the paint() method. Yes paint() will work most of the time but that is how painting is done when using AWT. This is Swing and for the last decade we have been promoting using the paintComponent() method which is the proper way to do painting in Swing. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks camickr for comprehensive answer, it's a lot better than "totally worng" :)